# List of Blazor components that implement an interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I am building a reusable Razor class library for Blazor components.

I have an interface that any Blazor component could implement:

```
public interface IControllableComponent
{
    void SetSomeValue(int someValue);
}
```

How can I get a List of all components that implement that interface?

```
public interface IControllableComponentManager
{
    void SetSomeValueForAllControllableComponents(int someValue);
}

public class ControllableComponentManager : IControllableComponentManager
{
    IList<IControllableComponent> _controllableComponentList;

    public ControllableComponentManager()
    {
        _controllableComponentList = ??? // how to populate this list?
    }

    public void SetSomeValueForAllControllableComponents(int someValue)
    {
        foreach (var controllableComponent in _controllableComponentList)
        {
            controllableComponent.SetSomeValue(someValue);
        }
    }
}
```

I want for my reusable Razor class library to be used in the code behind in different projects:

```
public class MyControllableComponentBase : ComponentBase, IControllableComponent
{
    protected int _someValue;

    public void SetSomeValue(int someValue)
    {
        _someValue = someValue;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to populate _controllableComponentList in ControllableComponentManager?

I would like to do this in a clean, proper way, without using reflection. Preferably in the style of ASP.NET Core with dependency injection.

The problem is that Blazor components are instantiated in Razor markup as `<Component></Component>` so I don't know how to get their references to add them to the `List<>`.

Comment: You can search for types using reflection and [`Assembly.GetTypes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes?view=netstandard-2.1). You can then filter those types by the interface they are implementing. Note that this is generally an expensive operation, so you should cache your results.

Comment: @poke That would be the last resort. I would really prefer to do it in a clean, proper way, without using reflection.

Comment: The only other way would be to actively create a list of all these component types. But if you want to detect them, then that is what reflection is for.

Comment: @poke No, I don't want to detect them. I am asking for a way to create a list. But since Blazor components are instantiated in Razor markup as `<Component></Component>` I don't know how to get their references to add them to the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you can do it as the following:

1. Define a service that stores a collection of the interface type
2. Expose a method to add a component, a method to remove a component, an event delegate to notify of addition, removal, etc.
3. Inject the service into the component you want to add itself to the service, and in the OnInitialized method do something like this:

   ```
   protected override void OnInitialized()
   {
       MyComponents.AddComponent(this);
       this.MyProperty = "I was born with the sun...";
   }
   ```

Comment: but my answer is very detailed ;) with all the implementation :) and come on, 20 seconds :)

Comment: It is not an issue to implement this. I can do it quite well. The point in question was to use the this keyword to add the component to the service from the OnInitialized method. But hey, I'm not insisting.

Comment: well, ok, fair is fair :)

Answer (score 4):

You can get a Blazor component reference using `@ref` but you can do that only within Razor markup.

To use a reference to a Blazor component outside Razor markup, the component must register itself.

To do that, you have to use a partial class for the component in the code behind:

```
public partial class ComponentContainer : ComponentBase, IComponentContainer
{
    public Type ComponentType { get; protected set; }

    public RenderFragment Component { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    protected IComponentContainerManager ComponentContainerManager { get; set; }

    public void SetComponentType(Type componentType)
    {
        ComponentType = componentType;

        StateHasChanged();
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ComponentContainerManager.RegisterComponentContainer(Name, this);

        Component = builder =>
        {
            if (ComponentType != null)
            {
                builder.OpenComponent(0, ComponentType);
                builder.CloseComponent();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Use `[Inject]` attribute to use dependency injection to inject a service where the component can register.

Use the `protected override void OnInitialized()` of the `ComponentBase` to register the component in the registration service.

```
public interface IComponentContainer
{
    Type ComponentType { get; }
    void SetComponentType(Type componentType);
}

public interface IComponentContainerManager
{
    void RegisterComponentContainer(string componentContainerName, IComponentContainer componentContainer);
    void SetComponentType(string componentContainerName, Type componentType);
    Type GetComponentType(string componentContainerName);
}

public class ComponentContainerManager : IComponentContainerManager
{
    readonly IDictionary<string, IComponentContainer> _componentContainerDict = new Dictionary<string, IComponentContainer>();

    public void RegisterComponentContainer(string componentContainerName, IComponentContainer componentContainer)
    {
        _componentContainerDict[componentContainerName] = componentContainer;
    }

    public void SetComponentType(string componentContainerName, Type componentType)
    {
        _componentContainerDict[componentContainerName].SetComponentType(componentType);
    }

    public Type GetComponentType(string componentContainerName)
    {
        return _componentContainerDict[componentContainerName].ComponentType;
    }
}
```

Now you can use `IComponentContainerManager` anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to dynamically create components, then you can use the [`RenderFragment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#razor-templates) concept for this. A render fragment is essentially a function that uses a [`RenderTreeBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.rendering.rendertreebuilder?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to create a component. This is what your Razor components are compiled to when you author `.razor` files.

For example, the following code creates a `RenderFragment` that just renders a single component:

```
Type componentType = typeof(MyControllableComponentBase);
RenderFragment fragment = builder =>
{
    builder.OpenComponent(0, componentType);
    builder.CloseComponent();
};
```

You could then assign that fragment to a property and render it dynamically within your Razor component:

```
<div>
   @Fragment
</div>

@code {
    public RenderFragment Fragment
    { get; set; }
}
```

This will solve the issue how to create components dynamically when you just know their type. However, it will not solve the problem that you want to call `SetSomeValue` on the component instances. For that, you will have to understand that you don’t really have control over the component instances: The render tree builder is responsible for creating the components from that virtual markup, so you don’t ever call `new ComponentType()`. Instead, you rely on the renderer to create the instance for you and *then* you could take a reference to the used instance and work with that.

You can use the `@ref` directive to [capture references to rendered component instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1#capture-references-to-components):

```
<MyControllableComponent @ref="controllableComponent" />

@code {
    private MyControllableComponent controllableComponent;

    private void OnSomething()
    {
        controllableComponent.SetSomeValue(123);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for trying, I really appreciate it, but I already know all that. Everything in your answer is already in the Microsoft documentation. The `@ref` only works inside Razor markup, so I can't use that to populate my `List`. Currently I am trying for components to register themselves on `protected override void OnInitialized()` to the `IControllableComponentManager` that they get with `[Inject]`

Comment: As I said, you _cannot_ populate the list the way you would want to do. You cannot create component instances yourself. You will need to remodel your approach to fit the component-based nature of Blazor.

Comment: I am not trying to create component instances myself. I am trying for them to register themselves in `protected override void OnInitialized()` to the `IControllableComponentManager` that they get with `[Inject]` :) And yes, your guess was spot on, "some value" is a `RenderFragment` in my case :) I am trying to make a manager class that would control all this :)

Comment: As it turns out, you can populate the list :) Thank you for your time! :)